# Prove that the minimum of these sets of $\mathbb R$ are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be **nonempty compact** set, and $B\subset \mathbb R$ be **nonempty closed**, and suppose $A\cap B=\emptyset.$

Then, from the compactness of $A$, there exists $r>0$ s.t. $A\subset[-r,r]$ and $B\cap [-r,r]\neq \emptyset.$

Define $B'$ as $B':=B\cap [-r,r]$.

Then, I want to show $$\min\{|a-b|\mid a\in A, b\in B\}=\min\{|a-b'|\mid a\in A, b'\in B'\}.$$

(I don't know whether this holds or not, but I think this holds by drawing picture. And I have already proved the existence of minimum of $\{|a-b|\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ and $\{|a-b'|\mid a\in A, b'\in B'\}$.)

---

Let $X=\{|a-b|\mid a\in A, b\in B\}, X'=\{|a-b'|\mid a\in A, b'\in B'\}$.

Since $B\supset B'$, I have $\min X\leqq\min X'$, so I have to show reverse.

Suppose $\min X<\min X'$.

Let $a_0\in A, b_0\in B$ minimize $X$,and $a_1\in A, b_1\in B'$ minimize $X'.$ Then $|a_0-b_0|<|a_1-b_1|\cdots (\ast)$

If $b_0\in B'$, then $|a_0-b_0|\geqq \min X'=|a_1-b_1|$ and this contradicts $(\ast)$, so $b_0\in B\setminus B'.$

And I have $B\setminus B'=B\setminus [-r,r]$, so $b_0\notin [-r,r]$.

Now, $a_0,a_1\in A\subset [-r,r]$ and $b_1\in B'=B\cap [-r,r]$ so I have $-r\leqq a_0,a_1,b_1 \leqq r.$

---

I cannot proceed from here.

Some contradiction seems to arise, but I cannot derive. Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true: for a counterexample, take $A=[0,1]\cup\{3\}$ and $B=\{2,\pi\}$ and $r=3$.